# Is it possible to group a set of html elements so that they move together?

Tags: css, html

When the browser size is changed/on different sized devices, I need a set of html elements that are all semantically related to remain together and move in a block. That is, if one of the elements move to the next "row" due to their not being enough width to contain the whole grouping, ALL of it should move down.

IOW, this is sort of like the "keep together" attribute that some groupings of items in a word processing document have.

To be a little more specific, say that I have collections of the following elements:

```
1) an anchor tag, filling out a first "column"
2) a collection of tags, to the right of the anchor tag, consisting of:
(a) a div, followed by a <br/>
(b) a cite, followed by a <br/>
(c) another div, followed by a <br/>
(d) two or three anchor tags that are aligned side-by-side at the bottom of the second "column"
```

So to sum up, if there is not enough room for the second "column" in a "row," rather than keep the  in the first "column" and moving the elements in the second column down to the next "row," the  in the first column should adhere to its siblings and always remain on the same "row" with them (I'm putting "row" and "column" in quotes because I'm not using an html table, and those exist only in a virtual sense).

If you're finding this a little hard to visualize (I don't blame you), check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W7CYC/8/

Note: wrapping the groupings into html5 s did not help.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="yearBanner">2013</div>
<section>
<a id="mainImage" class="floatLeft" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0299186342" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img height="240" width="160" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51usxIl4vML._SY346_.jpg"></a>

    <div id="prizeCategory" class="category">BIOGRAPHY</div>
    <br/>
<cite id="prizeTitle" class="title">Son of the Wilderness: The Life of John Muir</cite>

    <br/>
    <div id="prizeArtist" class="author">Linnie Marsh Wolfe</div>
    <br/>
    <img class="floatLeft" height="60" width="40" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51usxIl4vML._SY346_.jpg">
    <img class="floatLeft" height="60" width="40" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51usxIl4vML._SY346_.jpg">
    <img class="floatLeft" height="60" width="40" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51usxIl4vML._SY346_.jpg">
</section>
<section>
<a class="floatLeft" href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0299186342" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img height="240" width="160" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51usxIl4vML._SY346_.jpg"></a>

    <div class="category">BIOGRAPHY</div>
    <br/>
<cite class="title">Son of the Wilderness: The Life of John Muir</cite>

    <br/>
    <div class="author">Linnie Marsh Wolfe</div>
    <br/>
    <img height="60" width="40" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51usxIl4vML._SY346_.jpg">
    <img height="60" width="40" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51usxIl4vML._SY346_.jpg">
    <img height="60" width="40" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51usxIl4vML._SY346_.jpg">
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
.floatLeft {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.yearBanner {
    font-size: 3em;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 64px;
}
.category {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Consolas, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: Orange;
    width: 160px;
}
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Calibri, Candara, serif;
    color: Yellow;
    width: 160px;
}
.author {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: White;
    width: 160px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#prizeCategory').text("Changed Category");
$('#prizeTitle').text("Changed Title that spans two rows");
$('#prizeArtist').text("Changed Author and co-author");
$('#mainImage img').attr("src", "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61l0rZz6mdL._SY300_.jpg");
$('#mainImage img').attr("height", "200");
```

Comment: Maybe post a before/after picture, as I've got no idea wat you are describing here, and I've read through the whole post.

Comment: Yeah, a screenshot that shows what you want it to look like would make a big difference. Hard to tell at this point exactly what you're looking to do.

Comment: Are you just trying to get everything inside the <section> tag to wrap to be grouped together so the entire element wraps to the next line?

Comment: @ralph: the jsfiddle shows it all; to show what it does when you widen/narrow the "browser window" would take several screenshots; it an easily be seen by "messing with" the jsfiddle results pane.

Comment: @Jude: Yes, I want it all grouped together so that it moves together.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You group items simply with `div` (or if you want to use `section`, it is okay too). With a little hint of **CSS** you can group item inside wrapper. Unfortunately, there is no such attribute than *keep together* but you can do following:

```
section.wrapper {
  min-width: 400px; /* Minimum width of your wrapper element */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**min-width** helps you to keep elements inside wrapper in order. Select a value that best suits your situation.
**overflow** with value *hidden* lets your wrapper to understand and add width and height values of floated elements inside.
**display** with value *inline-block* let all of wrappers to order next to each other as long as there is enough space, if not, wrapper jumps to other row.

http://www.w3schools.com/ serves great sources to understand and learn CSS, HTML and web technologies in generally. Very useful.

**EDIT**
As I edited, **min-width** or **width** suits better in that situation than **max-width**

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand how to implement this, but I added this class to my CSS, and added class="wrapper" to the section elements, but one of the images in the first section still moves down to the second row. See http://jsfiddle.net/W7CYC/10/

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. Instead of `max-width` you should use property `min-width`. My bad, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an HTML issue, learn about using CSS absolute position inside of relative positioning:

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 1):

**[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) grids**

> Bootstrap includes a powerful mobile-first flexbox grid system for
>   building layouts of all shapes and sizes. It’s based on a 12 column
>   layout and has multiple tiers, one for each media query range. You can
>   use it with Sass mixins or our predefined classes.

code example :

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">.col-4</div>
    <div class="col-4">.col-4</div>
    <div class="col-4">.col-4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">.col-lg-4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">.col-lg-4</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">.col-lg-4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-4">.col-xl-4</div>
    <div class="col-xl-4">.col-xl-4</div>
    <div class="col-xl-4">.col-xl-4</div>
  </div>
```

Output:
This is default output:
[image]
and when size of my browser reduce to less than 1200px 
[image]

Here we have four row and the first row coumns will always at the same tow.

the second row will remain when max width is >=768px

the third row will remain when max width is >=992px and so on.I have inserted this details in G rids options

Here is a gif demo of output

[image]

you can mix this classes together.for example

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">first-col</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-3">second-col</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-3">third-col</div>
  </div>
```

mean if small devices I want three column with same with but in very small device I want to first-col be half of space and every two other column be 25% of with.

Now as you can see in every size you can set what behavior every row and every column should do and if you want to always move together you can use `col-*` classes without any prefix.
Grids Options

```
                (<768px)   (≥768px)   (≥992px)      (≥1200px)
Grid behavior   Horizontal at all times Collapsed to start, horizontal above breakpoints
Container width None (auto) 750px      970px          1170px
Class prefix    .col-xs-   .col-sm-    .col-md-       .col-lg-
# of columns    12
Column width    Auto       ~62px     ~81px  ~97px
Gutter width    30px (15px on each side of a column)
Nestable        Yes
Offsets         Yes
Column ordering Yes
```

[Here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) is more detail if you need